# Color of voting buttons hard to discern for colorblind users

Tags: feature-request, design, android-app, accessibility

I'm red-green colorblind. It's tough for me to discern the difference between the activated and non-activated color on the post voting buttons. Not impossible, but difficult enough where I have to stare for a few seconds and maybe squint a bit.

I've examined the colors on a Samsung Galaxy S3 and an HTC One E8, and played with the brightness settings on both. It remains difficult in all cases.

Increasing the saturation and/or luinosity value of the red activated color would help. In this case, I'd like to suggest also changing the color entirely. A blue or purple would fit the app's color scheme better than red in my opinion, though I'm not a professional or particularly skilled artist or designer. But R-G colorblindness is the most common variety, so shifting to a blue hue would theoretically reduce the number of negatively impacted users.

[Previous, related question about mobile web hyperlink colors.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228992/191706)

Comment: I just tested on Nexus 5 to simulate Protanomaly (red-green), and, ugh... I can understand what you mean. Perhaps adding a color-blind friendly mode on the Settings is another alternative... dunno.

Answer (score 3):

I completely agree that a solution is needed here, but I don't think simply changing the color is the answer since color blindness and low vision can vary significantly.  Using color alone to distinguish between the pressed and unpressed states of the button is ultimately a failure of [WCAG success criterion 1.4.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/visual-audio-contrast-without-color.html) anyway.  one possible more accessible solution would be to display a different graphic after the button is pressed.